# How to classify the Range by using R loop?

Tags: r, loops, range

I want to use R programming to classify the range but I failed by trying Update statement in SQL in R programming as R did not support update in the SQL packages. I choose to use SQL in R as  I am not good in loop for R.
Can anyone teach me how to do R loop by using this datasets?

Sample data :

```
f<- data.frame(
 id=c(8.5,9,12,17.548,25,30,36,45,57,65,78,82)

)
```

Expected Results:

```
f<- data.frame(
  id=c(8.5,9,12,17.548,25,30,36,45,57,65,78,82),
  Range=c("0%~10%","0%~10%","11%~20%","11%~20%","21%~30","21%~30","31%~40%","41%~50%","51%~60%","61%~70%","71%~80%","81%~90%")

   )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for cut().

Comment: @joran sorry .. what is cut() ? do you mind to explain more?

Comment: cut is a function in R.

Comment: @joran thanks you. I will research more on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
f$Range<-cut(f$id, breaks=c(0,10*1:9, 100), 
    labels=paste0(c(-1,10*1:9)+1,"%~",c(10*1:9, 100),"%"))
```

It will create a factor by splitting the values of "id" at the break points you specify. This will produce

```
       id   Range
1   8.500  0%~10%
2   9.000  0%~10%
3  12.000 11%~20%
4  17.548 11%~20%
5  25.000 21%~30%
6  30.000 21%~30%
7  36.000 31%~40%
8  45.000 41%~50%
9  57.000 51%~60%
10 65.000 61%~70%
11 78.000 71%~80%
12 82.000 81%~90%
```